# Spring CLI (v2.1.3) can't grab spring depenencies using Grab annotation in a simple groovy file

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spring-cli

Bellow I'm trying to create a simple groovy file that will expose a simple service saying hello, and also handle 404 errors by implementing [ErrorController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/ErrorController.html)  ( To avoid whitelabel error page, I could inject an HttpServletRequest and retrieve the status, but this isn't my concern for now )

```
package org.test

@Grab("spring-boot-autoconfigure")
@Grab("spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor")

@RestController
public class HelloController implements ErrorController{

  @GetMapping(value="/hello")
  public String sayHello(){
    return "Hey Joker";
  }

  @Override
  public String getErrorPath(){
    return "/error";
  }

  @GetMapping(value="/error")
  public String notFoundException(){
   return "{error:'NOT_FOUND', message:'Resource Not Found'}";
  }
}
```

So when I run `> spring run restController.groovy` I get :

```
file:/Users/xxxx/yyyy/restController.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class ErrorController
 @ line 3, column 1.
   @Grab("spring-boot-autoconfigure")
   ^

1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to start your controller and calling the hello endpoint, by adding the following import statement (don't know why only the ErrorController import is required)

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController
```